# Hide/Show Elements and Change Button

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, button, input

I would like to have a button that, when clicked, hides one element and shows another, and to have the button change text when clicked (I think I got this part). Also, I'd like to only display one of the elements upon loading the page, and when the button is clicked, to only display the other element. The code I am using currently almost accomplishes this correctly, but upon clicking the button, the hidden element is displayed (desired) but the other element that was displayed is not hidden. Here is my code (I am using basic JS, I don't want to use jQuery).

The HTML

```
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <span>E-Mail or Phone<br>
    </span>
    <button onclick="emph()" id="emphbtn" type="button">Use Phone</button>
  </div>
  <div id="phbox" style="display: none;">
    <label for="phone">Phone</label><input id="phone" type="tel" />
  </div>
  <div id="embox">
    <label for="mail">E-Mail</label><input id="mail">
  </div>
</body>
```

and the javascript

```
function emph() {
    // get the clock
    var myPhone = document.getElementById('phbox');

    // get the current value of the clock's display property
    var displaySetting = myPhone.style.display;

    // also get the clock button, so we can change what it says
    var switchbtn = document.getElementById('emphbtn');

    // now toggle the clock and the button text, depending on current state
    if (displaySetting == 'block') {
      // clock is visible. hide it
      myPhone.style.display = 'none';
      // change button text
      switchbtn.innerHTML = 'Use Phone';
    }
    else {
      // clock is hidden. show it
      myPhone.style.display = 'block';
      // change button text
      switchbtn.innerHTML = 'Use Email';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to toggle your email input embox

```js
function emph() {
  // get the clock
  var myPhone = document.getElementById('phbox');
  var myEmail = document.getElementById('embox');

  // get the current value of the clock's display property
  var displaySetting = myPhone.style.display;

  // also get the clock button, so we can change what it says
  var switchbtn = document.getElementById('emphbtn');

  // now toggle the clock and the button text, depending on current state
  if (displaySetting == 'block') {
    // clock is visible. hide it
    myPhone.style.display = 'none';
    myEmail.style.display = 'block';
    // change button text
    switchbtn.innerHTML = 'Use Phone';
  } else {
    // clock is hidden. show it
    myPhone.style.display = 'block';
    myEmail.style.display = 'none';
    // change button text
    switchbtn.innerHTML = 'Use Email';
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>E-Mail or Phone<br></span>
  <button onclick="emph()" id="emphbtn" type="button">Use Phone</button>
</div>
<div id="phbox" style="display: none;">
  <label for="phone">Phone</label><input id="phone" type="tel" />
</div>
<div id="embox">
  <label for="mail">E-Mail</label><input id="mail">
</div>
```